# Как переписать в textblock?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hql

```
@Repository
public class QuestionDtoDaoImpl implements QuestionDtoDao {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;
  @Override
  public Optional<QuestionDtoDao> getById(Long questionId,Long authorizedUserId){

    return
        SingleResultUtil.getSingleResultOrNull(entityManager.createQuery(
                "select q.id, " +
                    "q.title, " +
                    "q.description,  " +
                    "q.lastUpdateDateTime,  " +
                    "q.persistDateTime,  " +
                    "u.id,  " +
                    "u.fullName,  " +
                    "u.imageLink, " +
                    "coalesce((select sum(r.count) from Reputation r where r.author.id = u.id), 0), " +
                    "(select count(qv.id) from QuestionViewed qv where qv.question.id = q.id), " +
                    "(select count(a.id) from Answer a where a.question.id = q.id), " +
                    "(select quv.vote from VoteQuestion quv where quv.question.id = q.id and quv.user.id =:userId), " +
                    "(select count(b) from BookMarks b where b.question.id = :questionId and b.user.id = :userId), " +
                    "(select (case when count(a) > 0 then true else false end) from Answer a where a.question.id = :questionId and a.user.id = :userId)" +
                    "from Question  q " +
                    "LEFT join q.user u " +
                    "where q.id =:questionId")

            .setParameter("questionId", questionId)
            .setParameter("userId", authorizedUserId));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убираете ненужные кавычки и операторы конкатенации `+`:

```
    return SingleResultUtil.getSingleResultOrNull(entityManager.createQuery(
"""
select q.id, 
       q.title, 
       q.description, 
       q.lastUpdateDateTime, 
       q.persistDateTime, 
       u.id, 
       u.fullName, 
       u.imageLink, 
       coalesce((select sum(r.count) from Reputation r where r.author.id = u.id), 0), 
       (select count(qv.id) from QuestionViewed qv where qv.question.id = q.id), 
       (select count(a.id) from Answer a where a.question.id = q.id), 
       (select quv.vote from VoteQuestion quv where quv.question.id = q.id and quv.user.id =:userId), 
       (select count(b) from BookMarks b where b.question.id = :questionId and b.user.id = :userId), 
       (select (case when count(a) > 0 then true else false end) from Answer a where a.question.id = :questionId and a.user.id = :userId)
from Question q 
LEFT join q.user u 
where q.id =:questionId
"""
) //...
```